# исключить значение

Tags: mysql, sql

в столбце "отправитель" и "получатель" встречаются одинаковые фамилии (когда перевод осуществляется родственнику. Например:

Отправитель                 Получатель
Луканин Дмитрий             Луканина Светлана

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать такие записи в Select? Спасибо.

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Родственники могут иметь разные фамилии... или однофамильцы могут быть ни разу не родственниками.

Comment: Как убрать фамилии, которые в 1 строке присутствуют в столбце "отправитель" и столбце "получатель" ?

Comment: В общем случае никак, т.к. склонения ..